# Show ViewController Before Initializing PhoneGap

Tags: ios, ipad, cordova, uiwindow

We are currently building a mobile app for a client using PhoneGap and need to present a UIViewController to check for any web file changes before PhoneGap initializes. The app is done with PhoneGap 1.4.1 and I am trying to accomplish this by extending the PhoneGap project but not the PhoneGap library. Here is what I am doing in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
hostReach = [[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName: @"google.com"] retain];
internetReach = [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] retain];
//wifiReach = [[Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi] retain];

if (internetReach && hostReach) {
    self.app = application;
    self.options = launchOptions;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(updateFinished:) name: @"applicationUpdatingFinished" object: nil];

    NSLog(@"Windows:%i",[[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows count]);

    //[super application:app didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:options];
    CGRect screenBounds = [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ];
    self.window = [ [ [ UIWindow alloc ] initWithFrame:screenBounds ] autorelease ];
    UpdateViewController *updateVC = [[UpdateViewController alloc]init];
    [updateVC.view setFrame:screenBounds];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

/////////////////////
// END Check for updates
/////////////////////

    return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
```

And here is what I am firing after the UpdateViewController finishes.

```
-(void)updateFinished:(NSNotification*)n {
    [super application:app didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:options];
}
```

The update view controller does what its supposed to, checks and downloads any new web files. The problem is that it appears the Default.png image continues to display and when I add UpdateViewController's view, it places it under the Default.png image. this image does not go away until PhoneGap's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` gets called.

Any ideas on a better way, or why the UpdateViewController is displaying under the Default.png?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have code like this in your project?

> `self.viewController.useSplashScreen = YES;`

Comment: Unfortunately, the issue seems to be due to creating a `UIWindow` and then PhoneGapDelegate.m is recreating this window. When it recreates the `UIWindow`, the orientation is incorrect.